# What is best way to use nodejs with sqlite3 connections

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am playing with nodejs and sqlite3
The server will be used for making  rest calls using express.

Being kind of new to node, i have two questions on how to manage the db connection.

1 ) Do i open/connect to the

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
```

before the listener and then close the connection on exit of the server or in each route i open the connection and close when the rest call is complete.

2 ) how do i pass the connection to a separate route file? I tried based on some examples, but get the error message "Sever initialization failed  Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined" (see code below the exception)

```
Trace
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Work2\server.js:154:13)    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

these are

```
//server.js
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
var apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes')(db);

//apiRoutes.js
module.exports = (function (db) {

    router.get('/userlist', function (req, res, next) {
        res.json('{stuff...}');
    });
    return router;

})();
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's your `file`? seems like you're missing stuff.

Comment: this is just sudo code.    var file = config.services.server.db; 
What i am really asking is do i open and close each rest call or keep a connection open for the life of the server. thanks

Comment: Well I was asking because your second question, it's a bit lacking and you're showing some errors.

On the first question tho, keeping a connection pool (unless others need to use/share this sqlite file too) is a common pattern. But it depends also on your usage patterns, frequencies etc.